# Find the point (x, y) on the graph of $ y=\sqrt{x} $ nearest the point (0, 2).

Tags: calculus

The algebra is very hard .... can you see an easier way? I tried this...

$y=\sqrt{x}\iff y^2=x$ in this case the distance function $D(y)$ between $(y^2,y)$ and $(0,2)$ is such that
 $D^2(y)=y^4+(y-2)^2$ if we differentiate both sides we get $D(y)D^{'}(y)=2y^3+y-2$ to find the critical point we must have $2y^3+y-2=0 \rightarrow y\approx 0.83512 \rightarrow x\approx 1.67024$

My Ans is: (1.67024, 0.83512)
am I right?

Comment: The algebra is correct, but x is not solved for correctly.  If y is less than 1, so is x.

Comment: $y^2=x$ so $x\approx (0.835)^2$. Everything else looks correct.

Comment: Sure ... i did $2x$. Thanks

Comment: Can you please use well formed sentences and sensible formatting so that your question is legible?